# Mobicents diameter no connection to peer error message

Tags: diameter-protocol

I am new to mobicents diameter and followed the example [downloaded here](https://code.google.com/p/mobicents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/servers/diameter%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

Executing both ExampleClient and ExampleServer on the same machine with different ports the  "Result-code" is 3002

"Error-message" is "No connection to peer"

Where am I wrong?

Protocol error:

DIAMETER_UNABLE_TO_DELIVER         3002

```
  This error is given when Diameter can not deliver the message to
  the destination, either because no host within the realm
  supporting the required application was available to process the
  request, or because Destination-Host AVP was given without the
  associated Destination-Realm AVP.
```

client-jdiameter-config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Configuration xmlns="http://www.jdiameter.org/jdiameter-server">

<LocalPeer>
    <URI value="aaa://127.0.0.1:1812" />

    <IPAddresses>
        <IPAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
    </IPAddresses>
    <Realm value="mobicents.org" />
    <VendorID value="0" />
    <ProductName value="jDiameter" />
    <FirmwareRevision value="1" />
    <OverloadMonitor>
        <Entry index="1" lowThreshold="0.5" highThreshold="0.6">
            <ApplicationID>
                <VendorId value="0" />
                <AuthApplId value="333333" />
                <AcctApplId value="0" />
            </ApplicationID>
        </Entry>
    </OverloadMonitor>
</LocalPeer>

<Parameters>
    <AcceptUndefinedPeer value="false" />
    <DuplicateProtection value="true" />
    <DuplicateTimer value="240000" />
    <UseUriAsFqdn value="false" />
    <QueueSize value="10000" />
    <MessageTimeOut value="60000" />
    <StopTimeOut value="10000" />
    <CeaTimeOut value="10000" />
    <IacTimeOut value="30000" />
    <DwaTimeOut value="10000" />
    <DpaTimeOut value="5000" />
    <RecTimeOut value="10000" />
    <Concurrent>
        <Entity name="ThreadGroup" size="64" />
        <Entity name="ProcessingMessageTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="DuplicationMessageTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="RedirectMessageTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="PeerOverloadTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="ConnectionTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="StatisticTimer" size="1" />
    </Concurrent>

</Parameters>

<Network>
    <Peers>

        <Peer name="aaa://127.0.0.1:3868" attempt_connect="true" rating="1" />

    </Peers>
    <Realms>
        <Realm name="mobicents.org" peers="127.0.0.1"
            local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
            <ApplicationID>
                <VendorId value="0" />
                <AuthApplId value="333333" />
                <AcctApplId value="0" />
            </ApplicationID>
        </Realm>


    </Realms>
</Network>

<Extensions />

   </Configuration>
```

server-jdiameter-config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Configuration xmlns="http://www.jdiameter.org/jdiameter-server">

<LocalPeer>
    <URI value="aaa://127.0.0.1:3868" />

    <IPAddresses>
        <IPAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
    </IPAddresses>
    <Realm value="mobicents.org" />
    <VendorID value="0" />
    <ProductName value="jDiameter" />
    <FirmwareRevision value="1" />
    <OverloadMonitor>
        <Entry index="1" lowThreshold="0.5" highThreshold="0.6">
            <ApplicationID>
                <VendorId value="0" />
                <AuthApplId value="333333" />
                <AcctApplId value="0" />
            </ApplicationID>
        </Entry>
    </OverloadMonitor>

</LocalPeer>

<Parameters>
    <!-- set to true, we can safely remove client def in this case -->
    <AcceptUndefinedPeer value="true" />
    <DuplicateProtection value="true" />
    <DuplicateTimer value="240000" />
    <UseUriAsFqdn value="false" />
    <QueueSize value="10000" />
    <MessageTimeOut value="60000" />
    <StopTimeOut value="10000" />
    <CeaTimeOut value="10000" />
    <IacTimeOut value="30000" />
    <DwaTimeOut value="10000" />
    <DpaTimeOut value="5000" />
    <RecTimeOut value="10000" />
    <Concurrent>
        <Entity name="ThreadGroup" size="64" />
        <Entity name="ProcessingMessageTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="DuplicationMessageTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="RedirectMessageTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="PeerOverloadTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="ConnectionTimer" size="1" />
        <Entity name="StatisticTimer" size="1" />
    </Concurrent>

</Parameters>

<Network>
    <Peers>
        <!-- our client, lets define it -->
        <Peer name="aaa://127.0.0.1:1812" attempt_connect="false"
            rating="1" />

    </Peers>
    <Realms>
        <Realm name="mobicents.org" peers="127.0.0.1" local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
            <ApplicationID>
                <VendorId value="0" />
                <AuthApplId value="333333" />
                <AcctApplId value="0" />
            </ApplicationID>
        </Realm>


    </Realms>
</Network>

<Extensions />

    </Configuration>
```

Comment: If possible you should give more information about the error and the setup you use. Otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: It opens socket connection with server
{INFO  NetworkGuard - Open incomming connection Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=58921,localport=3868]} @ server

 and gets the response as above mentioned. The peer it is looking for is aaa://127.0.0.1:3868